# What's the proper representation of LinkedHashMap in JSON?

Tags: json, gson, linkedhashmap

When I serialize my `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` using GSON, I get

```
{"b":"a","a":"1","c":"2"}
```

and after deserializing I get back the elements in the right order. So everything works fine, but is there a guarantee that every tool works this way? Does the order of entries have any significance in JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Javascript hashes do not necessarily have a consistent order. For that, you'd probably want a representation like

```
[["b", "a"], ["a", "1"], ["c", "2"]]
```

or store the key order in a separate list, depending on what you are doing with it.

Comment: Actually, LinkedHashMap DOES guarantee key ordering.

Comment: You're right. LinkedHashMap does, but JavaScript's object keys don't, so a roundtrip via JSON won't necessarily preserve ordering if it goes through any other systems that parse it along the way.